# Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I readed almost all the post on stackoverflow with similar title but i can't find the solution of this problem. I'm using the https://photoswipe.com/ Photoswipe js plugin to make a `gallery with photos`. I have a problem, I downloaded the `Github` example (https://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/ZYbPJM) and on the dist folder I opened the index.html file and it's works well. I copied all the code on my site and don't work, It shows me on console **each time I click on the gallery**:

```
Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined
```

[image]

The code shows on the line 25 of this file: https://www.fundacioncb.es/wp-content/themes/construction/js/script.js

You can see the page with the error here: https://www.fundacioncb.es/cesion-espacio-badajoz/

**HTML Structure of the gallery:**

```
<h2>First gallery:</h2>

  <div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_a4c2eaa0cd_o.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024">
          <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_3c27ff3cd1_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
                                          <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption  1</figcaption>

    </figure>

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="964x1024">
      </a>
      <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x683">
      </a>
      <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 3</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x768">
      </a>
      <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 4</figcaption>
    </figure>


  </div>

<h2>Second gallery:</h2>

  <div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">



    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="964x1024">
          <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
      <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2.1</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x683">
          <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
      <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2.2</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x768">
          <img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5023/5578283926_822e5e5791_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
      <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2.3</figcaption>
    </figure>


  </div>
```

How Can i fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the error in your code on your webpage:  https://www.fundacioncb.es/cesion-espacio-badajoz/

Comment: You have a rogue `</p>` in your code between the last `</figure>` and `</div>`. (On your page, not in the code you posted here.) The browser tries to correct that, and that messes up your plugin.

Comment: Click any image of the gallery, you will see the error on the console.

Comment: @Ivar Wordpress all me that <p> and <br > by default on the text editor even tough I use the HTML editor. But I think that not fix the problem, is a JS problem not HTML problem

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga I'm still seeing it in the source of your page.

Comment: @Ivar I can't delete it, it's maked by Wordpress automatically, but I think that not fix the problem because is a JS problem, not HTML problem.

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga No, that is the problem. The script loops over the elements of `<div class="my-gallery" ...>` and tries to get the children of each element. It fails because the last `<p>` doesn't have children. Try to right click the first image and click "Inspect Element". Then scroll a bit down to the `<p></p>` (under the last `<figure>`), select it and delete it. And then try to see if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198824/discussion-between-pedro-corchero-murga-and-ivar).

Comment: All that being said, your question unfortunately is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions should be answerable without visiting any external links. In your case if you fix the issue, there is simply no way to reproduce the problem and therefore the question is useless for future readers, which is what Stack Overflow is about. You might consider deleting it, as it is going to be tough to make a reproducible in the question itself.

Comment: @Ivar he can post a demo fiddle, just fragment the problem to the smaller one, one which caused the issue.

Comment: @EugeneSunic That would be great. But until then the question remains off-topic (and should be closed as such).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the  p html element, because it is in you children list. Either remove it or try this:

```
if(linkEl.tagName == 'A' || linkEl.tagName == 'a') {
  size = linkEl.getAttribute('data-size').split('x');

            // create slide object
            item = {
                src: linkEl.getAttribute('href'),
                w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
                h: parseInt(size[1], 10)
            };



            if(figureEl.children.length > 1) {
                // <figcaption> content
                item.title = figureEl.children[1].innerHTML; 
            }

            if(linkEl.children.length > 0) {
                // <img> thumbnail element, retrieving thumbnail url
                item.msrc = linkEl.children[0].getAttribute('src');
            } 

            item.el = figureEl; // save link to element for getThumbBoundsFn
            items.push(item);
}
```

Comment: If i remove the <p></p> code that Wordpress generated on my site, it works, so how I can avoid Wordpress add me <p></p> on my html code in the html editor? Thanks.

Comment: by using the code that I posted..m, have you tried, basicaly just check if the tagName is equal to a (link)

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga any success?

Comment: Well, I fixed It deleting the empty spaces, thanks!

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga glad that you did, you can post your solution then if the above or other hasn't been helpful

Answer (score 0):

The solution was removing the `p` tags that Wordpress generated automatically on the Wordpress HTML editor.